# Get records from 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

In SQL Server, Is there any chance to display results from 3 tables? (Actually 4)

The 4th table contains 1 column similar to others. The values of similar columns of other 3 tables are different. In other words, if you select '1' in the 4th table column, the 1st table's results should displayed, if you select '2', the 2nd etc...

Comment: Can you add some examples of the layouts of the four tables?

Comment: Thank you for writing response. I've got an idea to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select fourth.pk,
case fourth.columnx
when '1' then one.columnx
when '2' then two.columnx
when '3' then three.columnx
else 'Exception to the rule?' 
end as 'Column A'
from fourth 
join one on fourth.joinid=one.joinid
join two on fourth.joinid=two.joinid
join three on fourth.joinid=three.joinid
```